# How to merge code of two person working on same branch with different commits?

Tags: python, django, git, gitlab

I and my colleague is working on a django (python) project and pushing our code on same branch(lets say branch1), as a beginner i know how to push the code on a particular branch but have no idea how pull and merge can be done. what should i do if i want full project including his codes and my codes together without overriding the whole file(lets say he made views1.py and i made views2.py, then after merge and all, the result must be views3.py)

- now views3.py contains my code and his code.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're welcome! [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs)

And one important thing! It makes no sense to work together on the same branch...

Answer (score 0):

well i completely understood what github exactly is, and also be aware that to work in a same branch for two people is not even a good idea. to work in a different branch, push your piece of code in it on daily basis and merge them solving the conflicts is always recommended.